# Requesting data from php through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Trying to request the posts made by users and loading more posts on user's request.
Getting Unexpected end of JSON input error while making ajax request in console.

Javascript

```
    $("#ajax_load_more").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET", 
          url: "action.php?action=morePosts",
          success: function(response){
                var result = $.parseJSON(response);        
                console.log(result);      
               }
    });
});
```

Making request to following code. 
$_SESSION['posts']) stores the number of posts to be loaded in the session.

```
if($_GET['action']=="morePosts"){
    if(isset($_SESSION['posts'])){
        $_SESSION['posts'] = $_SESSION['posts'] + 4;
        echo fetchAllPosts($_SESSION['posts']);
    } else if(isset($_SESSION['posts'])&& $_SESSION['posts']>4){
        $_SESSION['posts'] = 4;
    }  
}
```

Function for requesting all posts

```
    function fetchAllPosts2($array_length){
    $db = new db; //Class for database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT $array_length";
    $result = $db::query($query); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result); 
    $post = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$array_length; $i++){
        if(!empty($row[$i])){
            for($j=0;$j<count($row);$j++){
                $post['id']=$row[$i][0];
                $post['user_id']=$row[$i][1];
                $post['title']=substr($row[$i][2], 0 ,75);
                $post['text']=strip_tags(mb_substr($row[$i][3],0,50));
                $post['image']=$row[$i][4];
                $post['date']=$row[$i][5];
            }                           
            return json_encode($post);
        }
        elseif(empty($row[count($row)])){
            return json_encode(array());
        }
    } 
}
```

Please suggest better ways of achieving this functionality,

Comment: Did you initialize the session using `session_start()` and `$_SESSION['post']`? Did you check whether you are accessing the same session in each of your AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use echo instead of return and change ajax like also you din not echo the code inside elseif part:

```
$("#ajax_load_more").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: "action.php?action=morePosts",
          success: function(response){
                   console.log(response);    
               }
    });
});
```

Comment: No errors anymore, but still an empty response. Thanks

Comment: Please try to echo the result instead of return. And debug your php code

Comment: By the way why JSON.parse didn't work, although I have seen many people include it in their code.

Comment: This is not resolved completely yet, I have asked for suggestions to write it better

Comment: Problem may be with your echo or return statement JavaScript json shows error but json_encode don't display the error if data is empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 function fetchAllPosts2($array_length){
$db = new db; //Class for database
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT $array_length";
$result = $db::query($query); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
 $post = array();
if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 foreach($row as $key=>$value){
   $post[$key]['id']=$value['id'];
            $post[$key]['user_id']=$value['user_id'];
            $post[$key]['title']=substr($value['title'], 0 ,75);
            $post[$key]['text']=strip_tags(mb_substr($value['text'],0,50));
            $post[$key]['image']=$value['image'];
            $post[$key]['date']=$value['date'];
 }
  return json_encode($post);
}
 return json_encode(['error'=>"no post found"]);
}
```